# Catch panic on vec drain

Tags: rust

What is the best way to catch this panic?

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let u: Vec<_> = v.drain(.. 8).collect();
}
```

I know that I could do something like this

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    if v.len() < 8 {
        // error here...
    }
    let u: Vec<_> = v.drain(.. 8).collect();
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? I'd like to catch "all" errors, not just if the index is greater than the length. I couldn't find anything in the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/alloc/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain) beyond.

> Panics if the starting point is greater than the end point or if the end point is greater than the length of the vector.

Comment: It seems you are caching all errors. The only panic that can happen in that code snippet is the one you have pointed out, and you are avoiding it by checking the vector length before calling `drain`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`slice::get()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/primitive.slice.html#method.get):

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let range = 8..2;
    if v.get(range.clone()).is_some() {
      let u: Vec<_> = v.drain(range).collect();
    }
    else {
        // bad
    }
}
```